# How does it work with the magic WSDL URI query parameter?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, symfony

I'm building a Soap server within a Symfony application. As first step I created a controller with my "hello world" Soap action and defined the route for it:

**`routing.yml`**

```
api.soap.foo
    path: /soapapi/foo
    defaults: { _controller: SoapBundle\Controller\FooController:bar }
    methods: [GET, HEAD, POST]
```

**`FooController#bar(...)`**

```
protected function bar(Request $request)
{
    $autodiscover = new AutoDiscover();
    $autodiscover
        ->setClass(MyFooBarService::class)
        ->setUri('http://my-app.loc/soapapi/foo/bar')
        ->setServiceName('MyFooBarService')
    ;
    $wsdl = $autodiscover->generate();
    $wsdl->dump(__DIR__ . '/soapapi-foo-bar.wsdl');
    $server = new SoapServer(__DIR__ . '/soapapi-foo-bar.wsdl');
    $server->setObject($this->myFooBarService);
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');
    ob_start();
    $server->handle();
    $response->setContent(ob_get_clean());
    return $response;
}
```

Now, when I call `http://my-app.loc/soapapi/foo/bar` in a browser or using cURL (so via HTTP GET), I get an error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Bad Request</faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But when I call `http://my-app.loc/soapapi/foo/bar?wsdl`, I actually get the (generated) WSDL document. Why? I have not defined anywhere, that it should work like this. Why and how does this (magic) work? Is it Symfony specific magic?

Answer (score 4):

This is a great question.

No this is not Symfony specific, it's a behavior of the built-in SOAP server in PHP.  When the endpoint URL is accessed with `?wsdl` appended, the SOAP server will respond with the wsdl document that it was instantiated with in the constructor:

```
$server = new SoapServer(__DIR__ . '/soapapi-foo-bar.wsdl');
```

I haven't been able to find where this behavior is documented on the PHP website, but it clearly exists and is reproducible.

The code for the feature can be found in [PHP's source code starting on line 1369](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/soap/soap.c#L1369) and ending on line 1396.  The code checks if the request method is GET and checks for the presence of a 'wsdl' query parameter.

Comment: This behavior can be found from [php-src](https://github.com/php/php-src)'s [soap extension](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/soap/soap.c#L1550). Your answer is correct.